# Code keeps running the same for all items

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
friends_dict = {'2018': ['tom', 'jerry', 'darryl'],
                '2017': ['john', 'cait', 'ash']}

print(friends_dict['2017'])
print(friends_dict['2018'])

find_Friend = input('What friend are you looking for? >>').strip()

flag = True

for year, friends in friends_dict.items():
    for friend in friends:
        if friend != find_Friend:
            flag = False
            break
        else:
            print('That\'s your friend homie!')

if not flag:
    add_friend = input('Would you like to add friend? (y/or any key to quit) >>').lower()
    if add_friend == 'y':
        ask_Year = input('What year would you like to add them to? >>').strip()
        if year in friends_dict.items() == ask_Year:
            friends_dict[ask_Year].append(find_Friend)

        else:
            friends_dict[ask_Year] = [find_Friend]

    else:
        print('Sounds good g! Have a good day.')        


print(friends_dict)
```

My code keeps on running the same even when I make the boolean flag False. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the mistakes I found:

(a). You are comparing only the first element in the list to the value entered by the user. You have to check if the `find_Friend` entered by user is present in the entire list:

So replace the first `for` loop with following lines:

```
for year, friends in friends_dict.items():
    if find_Friend not in friends:
        flag = False
    else:
        flag = True
```

(b). If the `find_Friend` doesn't exist in ANY list, then you ask for the year to be entered. All you have to do is to check if that `year` exists in `friends_dict`. Since year is a key to the dict, you can just use the `in` operator to see if the entered value, i.e. `ask_Year`, exists in the `friends_dict`. So replace the `if not` lines with:

```
if not flag:
    add_friend = input('Would you like to add friend? (y/or any key to quit) >>').lower() 
    if add_friend == 'y':
        ask_Year = input('What year would you like to add them to? >>').strip()
        if ask_Year in friends_dict:
            friends_dict[ask_Year].append(find_Friend)
        else:
            friends_dict[ask_Year] = [find_Friend]
    else: print('Sounds good g! Have a good day.')
else: print('That\'s your friend homie!')
```